# Read more toggle button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, processwire

I have three services, with a read more button, I want to them all show some text and when the user clicks the read more button it to show more but struggling to get the text to toogle. I am using a CMS called processwire. I have some jquery but was wondering were I am going wrong?

```js
$("#designLink").addClass("active");

$("#designLink").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#DesignService").show();
    $("#PrintService").hide();
    $("#PublishingService").hide();
    $("#DesignService").removeClass("visuallyhidden");
    $("#designLink").addClass("active");
    $("#printLink").removeClass("active");
    $("#publishingLink").removeClass("active");
});

$("#printLink").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#DesignService").hide();
    $("#PrintService").show();
    $("#PublishingService").hide();
    $("#PrintService").removeClass("visuallyhidden");
    $("#designLink").removeClass("active");
    $("#printLink").addClass("active");
    $("#publishingLink").removeClass("active");
});

$("#publishingLink").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#DesignService").hide();
    $("#PrintService").hide();
    $("#PublishingService").show();
    $("#PublishingService").removeClass("visuallyhidden");
    $("#designLink").removeClass("active");
    $("#printLink").removeClass("active");
    $("#publishingLink").addClass("active");
});
```

```html
    <div class="container--content">

      <div class="home-services cf">
        <h2 class="text-center">Our Services</h2>
        <div class="home-services__services-container">
          <div class="home-services__services grid flex">
            <div class="service-box lap-and-up-one-third grid__item">
<!-- design section -->
              <p class="service-box__link">Design</p>
              <img class="service-box__icon" src="<?php echo $config->urls->templates ?>public/images/icon-design.svg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='icon-design.png'" alt="" title=" Design Work">
 <!--
   design text
          -->
              <?php echo "{$page->designServiceText}"; ?>

              <div class="toggle-box">
                <input type="checkbox" style="display: none" id="toggle-box__toggle">
                <label class="button" for="toggle-box__toggle">Toggle read more</label>
                <div><?php echo "{$page->designServiceTextMore}"; ?></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--
printing section
            -->
            <div class="service-box lap-and-up-one-third grid__item">
              <p class="service-box__link">Print</p>
              <img class="service-box__icon" src="<?php echo $config->urls->templates ?>public/images/icon-print.svg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='icon-print.png'" alt="" title="">
 <!--
print text
          -->
              <?php echo "{$page->printServiceText}"; ?>
              <div class="toggle-box">
                <input type="checkbox" style="display: none" id="toggle-box__toggle2">
                <label class="button" for="toggle-box__toggle2">Toggle read more</label>
                <div><?php echo "{$page->printServiceTextMore}"; ?></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--
publishing section
          -->
            <div class="service-box lap-and-up-one-third grid__item">
              <p class="service-box__link">Publishing</p>
              <img class="service-box__icon" src="<?php echo $config->urls->templates ?>public/images/icon-publishing.svg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='icon-publishing.png'" alt="" title=" Publishing Work">
 <!--
publishing text
          -->
              <?php echo "{$page->publishingServiceText}"; ?>
              <div class="toggle-box">
                <input type="checkbox" style="display: none" id="toggle-box__toggle3">
                <label class="button" for="toggle-box__toggle3">Toggle read more</label>
                <div><?php echo "{$page->publishingServiceTextMore}"; ?></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="home-services__divider" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: If possible, try to recreate this scenario in http://jsfiddle.net/ and share with us

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hja305w8/2/

Comment: Please rephrase the issue. All three boxes expand and collapse as they should

Comment: I just realised it does exactly what I want herebut locally it doesn't do this with the text that is the processwire cms.

Comment: You may be using jQuery (not sure what the $ is), maybe that's not enabled on the system. Also, the js is looking for ID's that don't exist in the HTML

Comment: How do I enable it on the system?

Comment: I'm not familiar with processwire. I'm not sure where you took this code from, what you expect to do it etc. but if you have copied the JS code from somewhere else it may be incompatible.

Comment: Like I said before the `publishingLink` for example is nowhere to be seen in your HTML. Either you've misunderstood example code from somewhere else or you haven't shown us the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to classes that do not exist in the code. `publishingLink` is only mentioned in the Javascript, not in the HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good use case for the `<details>` tag.

- On `DOMContentLoaded`, get all `<summary>` elements.
- And append `<span class="readmore">Read More...</span>` to each of them.
- Then in the css set all elements with the `readmore` class to `display:block` (or anything except `none`)
- And add a new css rule to hide the `readmore` element for any `<details>` element that has the `open` attribute

The only caveat is that the HTML won't validate if you put `<p>` tags inside the `<summary>` element. `<h2>` tags will validate though!

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const summaries = document.querySelectorAll('summary');
  const readmore = document.createElement('span');
  readmore.classList.add('readmore');
  readmore.innerText = 'Read More...';
  for (const summary of summaries) {
      summary.append(readmore.cloneNode(true));
    }
});
```

```css
details > summary .readmore {
display:block;
}

details[open] > summary .readmore {
display: none;
}

summary > h2,
.readmore {
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
 }
 
.readmore:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
  <h2>Article Title</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</summary>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</details>
```